# Best way to post and get back html elements in classic asp for validation without session vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic, jscript

I am currently working on some pages that require a post to an asp validation script, then repopulating the data (that hasn't been saved to the DB yet) back into their respective elements on the form.

I was simply going to use session vars for this but since the form is set up to have dynamically generated elements I think it will crash the site depending on how many of these elements are generated. As of right now, I am posting to Script B from Script A and then redirecting back to Script A.

I was going to simply grab the Request.Form elements and put them into a session in Script B, validate, then redirect to Script A. Then in Script A loop through the Session vars with my request.form elements and then slap those back into their respective elements. Any thoughts would be appreciated greatly.

I am looking into something like Server.Execute but I haven't used that so I am unfamiliar with it. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Have you thought about maybe using jquery ajax to send data to the validation script, and then deal with the response?  This way the user doesn't have to leave the page.

Comment: I agree, do it with ajax and jQuery.

Comment: Ok. I am not familiar with that approach. What is the gist of it? Execute my validation script from my form script and it sends me back something similar to a Request?

Comment: I've added an answer with the basic shell of a solution.  Without your code and form details I can't really help more, but what I've done should give you a decent starting point (hopefully).

Comment: ... serialize your form, you can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment earlier, you could do something like this with jQuery (albeit with more meaningful code for you) -

```
$("some button you have on your form").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "url of the script that will perform the validation?val1=something&val2=something&val3=something",
      success: function(data) {
        //Here, do something with the returned 'data' from your validation script
        //This could be highlighting incorrect data, or filling form fields with
        //new data of some kind...
      }
   });

});
```

This would be the simplest kind of setup to get you what you want.  For more details on how ajax works in jQuery, [go here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

In your classic asp code, you just need to process the data sent by the ajax function and return something (via response.write(xxxx)) that will be sent back to the calling function and processed by the code under function(data), using the 'data' variable to access the returned values.

Your code might look something like this based on the type of ajax request sent above:-

```
<%
if request.querystring("val1") = something then
    'do something with the data
end if

'Etc

Response.write(some kind of response that you can deal with in the calling function)

%>
```